# Issue With Desktop Save Mode Not Saving

Tags: emacs, save

Recently I have been having an issue with desktop save mode where it will not actually save my desktop. In the echo bar it says "Error while saving the desktop..." After typing no it says "Opening output file: no such file or directory, then gives the location to the path of the file". After saving a .emacs.desktop file then restarting emacs I noticed that it is saving the buffer locations in that file but is not loading that file. Thanks. Also I am not sure what has caused this to happen as it was working a couple weeks backs and nothing has changed that should make a difference.

The only thing i have in my .emacs for the desktop mode is

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Comment: Can you paste your configuration for Desktop?

Comment: Yeah sorry I thought I put it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for desktop.el [here](http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/dev/third/emacs/lisp/desktop.el), it looks like the error is bubbling up from `desktop-kill`, which runs when you exit Emacs. The first thing I'd try is to check that the directory where it tries to save the desktop is sane.

Looking at the code in `desktop-kill`, it only tries to do anything if the variable `desktop-dirname` is non-nil. But that only gets set when you run `M-x desktop-save` for the first time: are you sure that it's set to something sensible? To check its value quickly, you can type `M-: desktop-dirname RET` and it should appear as a string in the message area.

If the directory is something sensible (the directory exists and you can write to it...), then I'm not sure. You'll probably have to give more information to get a solution, and it's not really clear that it's an ideal question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok so i did that and for some reason its saving it to c:/windows/system32. But the thing is i set the save path to a different place that is more sensible. c:/users/shantanu/desktop/emacs/

Comment: And I presume it still doesn't work? To check if it's a problem based on this, try evaluating the expression: `(file-writable-p (expand-file-name desktop-basefilename desktop-dirname))`. If you get T as a result, I'm afraid I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Ok, your best hope for debugging further is first to evaluate `(setq debug-on-error t)`. Then when something goes wrong, you'll get a backtrace with much more information on what was trying to run.

Comment: Ok i have done that, but i also updated to a new version of emacs and it is working. I am still going to look into what caused this to happen though.

Comment: same Problem - updated to emacs 24.3 which solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

i should hazard that you get this error by creating a shortcut in the windows start manual via clicking `addpm.exe` in the `...\emacs-version\bin\` folder.

you can further modify the shortcut. go to its `property->shortcut` tab, you will find that the `Target` has value like `...\emacs-version\bin\runemacs.exe`, while `Start in` is void. try to fill `Start in` with the corresponding folder `...\emacs-version\bin` (actually most directories would be fine, just don't leave it blank), then everything is fine. still, the machanism behind this remains unclear to me.

or you could always creat your own shortcut manually, only make sure that the target is `runemacs.exe`, not any other exe file.